# Weird Side Effect with Malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

So i'm writing a C program for a simple shell. Not too difficult but I've run into one really odd problem that I can't explain. I'm attempting to create a two dimensional array within a struct to represent a command and its arguments. For the command "ls -l" for example i'd like to have the first element "ls" and the second "-l". Seems to work fine other than that malloc changes the "ls" to "ms". The same thing for other commands, the first character is incremented; not before the malloc and immediately afterward.

This is the hunk of code in question....

```
    printf ("PRE MALLOC: %c\n", ret_val->args[0][0]);
    printf ("[0] %p\n", ret_val->args[0]);
    ret_val->args[1] = (char*) malloc ((3) * sizeof (char));
    printf ("[0] %p\n", ret_val->args[0]);
    printf ("[1] %p\n", ret_val->args[1]);
    printf ("POST MALLOC: %c\n", ret_val->args[0][0]);
```

All I'm attempting to accomplish is to allocate a 3 ( -l + the null ) character array to hold the "-l" in args[1]. These aren't really going to be hardcoded either but I figured it makes the point better.

The output produced it this...

PRE MALLOC: l

[0] 80613b0

[0] 80613b0

[1] 80613b8

POST MALLOC: m

So the two addresses don't overlap or anything strange but the first character of the first array is incremented? I'm sorry if I'm overlooking something stupid. But I can't think of any reason why this would happen.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Here is much more code, for some context.

```
int lcv;
int numargs;
int numchars;
int offset;
int bool;

TCommand* ret_val;
char** tmp;

ret_val = (TCommand*) malloc ( sizeof (TCommand) );
ret_val->cmd = NULL;
ret_val->args = NULL;

/* CMD */
lcv = 0;
numargs = 0;
numchars = 0;
offset = 0;

/* Remove initial whitespace */
while (input[offset] == ' ')
{
    ++offset;
}

lcv = offset;

/* Loop through command string */
while ( input[lcv] != ' ' && input[lcv] != 0 && input[lcv] != '&')
{
    ++numchars;
    ++lcv;
}

ret_val->cmd = (char*) malloc ( (numchars+1) * sizeof(char));

/* Copy to command string */
memcpy (ret_val->cmd, &(input[offset]), (numchars * sizeof (char)));
ret_val->cmd[numchars] = 0;
offset += numchars;

/* Copy command string into first argument */
ret_val->args = (char**) malloc ( sizeof (char*));
memcpy (ret_val->args[numargs++],ret_val->cmd, (numchars+1) * sizeof(char));

bool = 1;
while ( bool )
{

    /* Remove initial whitespace */
    while (input[offset] == ' ')
    {
        ++offset;
    }

    lcv = offset;

    if ( input[lcv] == 0 )
    {
        bool = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++numargs;
        tmp = (char**) realloc (ret_val->args, numargs * sizeof (char*));
        ret_val->args = tmp;
        numchars = 0;

        while ( input[lcv] != ' ' && input[lcv] != 0 &&
            input[lcv] != '&')
        {
            ++numchars;
            ++lcv;
        }

                printf ("PRE MALLOC: %c\n", ret_val->args[0][0]);
                printf ("[0] %p\n", ret_val->args[0]);
                    ret_val->args[1] = (char*) malloc ((2) * sizeof (char));
                printf ("[0] %p\n", ret_val->args[0]);
                printf ("[1] %p\n", ret_val->args[1]);
                printf ("POST MALLOC: %c\n", ret_val->args[0][0]);
                fflush(stdout);
        memcpy (ret_val->args[numargs-1],&(input[offset]),numchars * sizeof (char));
        ret_val->args[numargs-1][numchars] = 0;
        offset += numchars;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `ret_val->args` allocated?

Comment: What is the definition of the ret_val struct?

Comment: Sorry
This is the struct definition
typedef struct
{
        char* cmd;
        char** args;
        int background_flag;
} TCommand;

Comment: ret_val -> args is realloced for each additional argument detected.
                        ret_val->args = (char**) realloc (ret_val->args, numargs * sizeof (char*));

Comment: Seems like heap corruption. Probably something in how you allocate the args table. May I suggest running your program under a memory debugger such as Valgrind?

Comment: Alrighty. I've never used the tool before but it looks promising and I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: It might help us more if you mentioned your development platform (OS, compiler etc)

Comment: Oh sure, sorry for forgetting that as well. I'm compiling on Solaris with gcc.

Comment: Your `realloc()` statement is a recipe for leaking if memory reallocation fails - never assign the result of `realloc()` to the variable you pass in as the first argument.

Comment: Post some more code.  Your error is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
/* Copy command string into first argument */
ret_val->args = (char**) malloc ( 2 * sizeof (char*));
memcpy (ret_val->args[numargs++],ret_val->cmd, (numchars+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Copies through the uninitialised pointer `ret_val->args[0]`.  Try:

```
/* Copy command string into first argument */
ret_val->args = malloc(2 * sizeof ret_val->args[0]);
ret_val->args[numargs] = malloc(numchars + 1);
memcpy(ret_val->args[numargs++], ret_val->cmd, numchars + 1);
```

(Note that `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 by the language).

Comment: Oh geez. You're right. Problem solved. Sorry, I didn't see that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the routine. Thanks for all the help, great forum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the fragment you show; it is somewhere in the code you don't show.

So, you need to build your example from the ground up - showing the structure declarations, the memory management and copying you do for the structures.

Comment: Yea I think you're right. I'll have to look through it more carefully. Thanks for the help. I'll stop back if I can't track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic example of heap corruption.

What you are seeing is most probably the result of the `malloc()` call overwriting the string that `args[0]` points to with its return value. This can happen if the `args` array does not actually have enough space for the second argument. By writing into `args[1]` you are overwriting the contents of the string that is pointed to by `argv[0]` and that I suspect you allocate with an `strdup()` call or similar immediately after allocating the `args` array.

Since the heap grows upwards, and assuming no intervening `free()` calls, by overstepping the bounds of a dynamically allocated array there is an increased chance of messing with the area allocated immediately afterwards.

I'll hazard a guess and recommend that you check the allocated size for the `args` array by printing out the arguments for the `realloc()` call and checking its return value.

EDIT:

Apparently not in this case. It seems that the `argv[0]` pointer could actually be uninitialised, without causing a segmentation fault. Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to see how args[0] is allocated, and how it is given a value.

I can make a few suggestions, though they won't fix the allocation problem:

1. It is not necessary to cast the result of `malloc()`, and while one has limited ability to change a type in an already-written C program, there is no reason to *deliberately* lower the level of abstraction by open-coding duplicate type information.

   Old texts and old code examples often cast `malloc()` because C did not always have a `void *` type, and even after it arrived people wrote in the old style by habit and for code portability to old compilers. But you are unlikely these days to ever need to compile for the PDP-11.
2. `sizeof(char)` is, by C99, 1, so it's OK to just say `malloc(3)`, and it reads slightly easier because it's shorter.  And if you know it's `"-l"`, you may as well just use `"-l"`.